# can android mobile vision api get json result like web vision api?

Tags: android, json, api, mobile, vision

I'm developing android app using mobile vision api

the docs in vision api says it provide recognize face, barcode and text.

but I hope to find is smog, light and fire that is recognized in web vision api.

is there way to recognize those things in mobile vision api?

I think the best way to get the results is getting result as json.

please help me

thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to look into computer vision and deep learning solutions for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Google Mobile Vision is limited to recognizing Face, Barcodes and Text.

For the use case that you are looking for, try looking into [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) by Google.
It recognizes different kinds of objects and environments and output of it can be obtained in a JSON format.